# How to implement an (N x N) x M matrix on Matlab?

Tags: matlab, loops, math, matrix, grid-layout

Suppose we have a 2D meshgrid with N points (that is N = N<sub>x</sub>*N<sub>y</sub>, where N<sub>x</sub> is the number of grid points in the x axis and N<sub>y</sub> is the number of grid points in the y axis) on the grid and we have a 1D domain embedded in our meshgrid which we discretise to have M points.

Now, let A = F<sup>(ij)</sup><sub>m</sub> be a system matrix (for some function F, with a two dimensional parameter), where the i indexes from 1 to N<sub>x</sub>, j indexes from 1 to N<sub>y</sub> and m indexes from 1 to M.

A is an M x N matrix. So it has M column and N rows. Clearly, implementing the M columns shouldn't be very difficult but I am having trouble envisaging how we'd implement the N rows.

In particular, we would have something like

```
[F^(11)_1 , F^(11)_2 - F^(11)_1 , .... , F^(11) _M - F^(11) _(M-1)]
[F^(12)_1 , F^(12)_2 - F^(12)_1 , .... , F^(12) _M - F^(12) _(M-1)]
                                  ....
[F^(1Ny)_1 , F^(1Ny)_2 - F^(1Ny)_1 , .... , F^(1Ny) _M - F^(1Ny) _(M-1)]
[F^(21)_1 , F^(21)_2 - F^(21)_1 , .... , F^(21) _M - F^(21) _(M-1)]
                                  ....
[F^(NxNy)_1 , F^(NxNy)_2 - F^(NxNy)_1 , .... , F^(NxNy) _M - F^(NxNy) _(M-1)]
```

Thus M columns and N=N<sub>x</sub>*N<sub>y</sub> rows.

I am trying to implement this on Matlab and I guess it should begin something like:

```
x = 1:.5:10;
y = 1:.5:10;
[X Y] = meshgrid(x,y); % create mesh grid
Nx = length(x);
Ny = length(y);
N = Nx*Ny; % number of points in our mesh grid
M = 20; % arbitrary choice
Y0 = 5; % fixed y vector
F = besselh(0,2,norm([X Y]-[X(:,m),Y0])); % a 2D function we want to sum over the loop
A = zeros(M,N); % preallocate the memory
for i = 1:Nx
    for j = 1:Ny
        for m =1:M
        A = F(i,j,m);    
        ...
```

But I don't really have too much of an idea. Maybe a loop isn't even the way to go

Note that for those commenting about the readability I provide a snippet of the mathematical problem I am dealing with (although not all details are important, of course):

[image]

Note that rho is a vector on the Euclidean plane and the i and j subscripts represent the x and y component respectively. rho_{x_s,y_s} is just a fixed point in the Euclidean plane and lambda > 0 is a constant.

Comment: It's a 3D array, right?  What's the problem?

Comment: @duffymo It's not a 3D array since A should belong to the complex matrices with M columns and N rows. N happens to be the product of Nx and Ny. You can observe the dimension of the matrix in the bracket thingy I made with the F entries which shows what A should look like.

Comment: what is `m` and what's its dimensions?

Comment: @LeanderMoesinger Sorry, `m = 1:M`, I made a mistake in my code and wrote `k` instead (I will correct that now)

Comment: Just to clear things up: `[F^(11)_1 & F^(11)_2 - F^(11)_1 & .... & F^(11) _M - F^(11) _(M-1)]` is currently just a series of logical statements and would result in a single 0 or 1. Or did you mean `,` instead of `&` which would lead to a vector of `M` length?

Comment: @LeanderMoesinger Yes, exactly, I meant `,` since that should be a vector of length `M`

Comment: this is confusing the hell out of me. It looks like you're trying to adapt latex code for here ... if you do have the latex code for this I can convert it for you so the question makes sense.

Comment: Ah, I see. You can use the fact that if you index a 3-dimensional matrix A as `A(:,:)` instead of `A(:,:,:)`, this will treat the 2nd and 3rd dimensions columnwise. Combine this with `permute` to make your invariant column a row, and then transpose, and you're in business.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou I provided a picture of the Latex code (although not all details in it are necessarily of importance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example. Your `F` isn't valid matlab code, so I've replaced it here with a 'toy' function, just to show you the method.

```matlab
% Parameters
x = 1:.5:10; y = 1:.5:10; [X Y] = meshgrid(x,y); % create mesh grid
Nx = length(x); Ny = length(y); N = Nx * Ny;
M = 20; % arbitrary choice

% Example 'F' Function (here in the form of an 'anonymous function' handle);
F = @(i,j,m) (10*i - 5*j) * m;

% Evaluate F at each i,j,m index and collect as a 3D array.
A = zeros(M, Nx, Ny); % preallocation
for i = 1:Nx, for j = 1:Ny, for m =1:M
  A(m, i, j) = F(i, j, m);
end, end, end

A = reshape(A, [M, N]);
A = A.' % transpose to place 'M' dimension as columns and rest as rows.
```

Comment: Aargh. The names I chose don't correspond to the ones in your latex, but, anyway, you get the point :)

Comment: Indeed, I get that I would switch `A` with `F` and vice versa, but I am slightly confused about whether I would stick with `A(:,:,1)` or write `A(:,:,i)` and loop `i=1:Nx` and also an idea of what I would write instead of `magic` and `magic+1`? Excuse my naivety.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I was answering the general technique. Well, there's a couple of things about your code, the first is, F isn't really a "function". But, if it were, such that for each `i,j,m` triplet it produces a scalar, then you could collect this as A(i,j,m) = F(i,j,m) at each step of the iteration, to produce the 3D matrix A.

Comment: Ok, I've edited the answer to show a more complete example. I've also used `reshape` instead of linear indexing ... it should make a bit more sense to you now.